# GPO Editor - Password complexity number of days grayed out

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

Firstly thank you for all your help! I recommend this site to every sysadmin I meet but I rarely post.

I've currently moved from an MSP into internal IT and I've came across and Using MS Sever 2016 trying to altar the password complexity to 12 from 8 is this possible?

Comment: Hi, as wrote it's unclear, can you share a printscreen of the grayed settings please, and do you use the domain admin account to edit the GPO ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/aLHAyCG.png >>> 
Sorry I was unaware.

Comment: For your actual problem, it's you use the local group policy console (gpedit.msc), you should edit the Defualt Domain Policy (with the domain Goup Policy's Console), which are where those settings are stored.

Comment: Oops Thank you so much!! Issue resolved. Thank you for all the help and the speedy response!

Comment: I will write an answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, it's you use the local group policy console (gpedit.msc) from the DC.

You should edit the Default Domain Policy (with the domain Goup Policy's Console), which are where those settings are stored.